# What is the word that describes the inner curve of a crescent?

Tags: terminology, geometry

What is the word that describes the inner curve of a crescent? As in a crescent moon?

Comment: Crescents are often drawn as two arcs of circles.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about physics.

Comment: Close away, Jon...I got my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a crescent is delimited by two circle segments.
But in the case of the moon, the inner curve is half of an ellipse. 
So it is not the usual "crescent" even though we use the same word to name it.

Answer (score 2):

The inner crescent you describe can be said to be the line that divides the light from the shadow on the moons surface.

This is known as "The Lunar Terminator".

Hope this helps.